# Why printf() in while() as a condition prints different output

Tags: c, while-loop

### First code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    while(printf("Hello"))
    return 0;
}
```

Produces only `Hello` as a output

### Second code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    while(printf("Hello"));
    return 0;
}
```

Second code prints `Hello` for infinite times.

### Third code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    while(printf("Hello"))
    {}
    return 0;
}
```

Third code also prints `Hello` for infinite times.

### Compiler used  - GCC 9.0.1

### why this is happening?

Comment: Aha, now there's something that does compile. And it is rather obvious why it executes the print only once.

Comment: For first code we get the error without return 0;

Comment: Hint: in the first piece of code, what is the body of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`while` takes a statement after the closing `)`.

[6.8.6 Iteration statements](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5)

```
 iteration-statement:
                while ( expression ) statement

 ....
```

In

```
while(printf("Hello"))
    return 0;
```

that statement (which is basically `while`'s argument) is `return 0;` ([6.8.6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6))

In

```
while(printf("Hello"));
```

the statement is `;` (an empty (null)/expression statement ([6.8.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.3))).

In

```
while(printf("Hello")){}
```

it's an empty compound statement (`{}`, [6.8.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.2)), which is semantically equivalent to `;`.

Your code snippets are examples of misleading whitespace—where the whitespace makes humans understand things differently from a compiler.

Less misleading renderings would be:

```
while(printf("Hello"))
    return 0;
```

,

```
while(printf("Hello"))
    ; //or perhaps a {} instead of the null statement
```

and

```
while(printf("Hello"))
    {}
```

Answer (score 2):

`printf` returns number of characters printed (which is 5). Any non zero number evaluates to true. So the loop is an infinite loop.

The rest depends on what happens withing the loop. In the second and third cases, the loops are empty (contain no statements) so they keep executing

In the first case, `return 0` is executed within the loop. Return breaks the control flow out of the loop causing the loop (and in this case the program) to stop executing

Answer (score 2):

In your first code snippet, the `return 0;` statement is part of the `while` loop's 'body'; in fact, it is the *entirety* of that body! So, on the first run through that loop, the program exits (because that what `return 0;` does when executed in `main`) and the loop is, thus, abruptly terminated.

In the second and third snippets, you have an *empty* body for the loop, but that does not prevent it from running, as the `printf("Hello")` function call will return the number of characters that were output - which will be non-zero, and thus interpreted as "true".

Answer (score 2):

In the first one the body of the `while` is the `return 0` so it will return after the first iteration. Meanwhile with the other two version is the same, having an empty body so they infinitely going on doing nothing but the condition is keep evaluating which will print "hello".

```
    while(printf("Hello"))
    return 0;
```

is same as

```
    while(printf("Hello"))
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Code:**

`printf("Hello")` returns the number of characters.

When `printf("Hello")` is used inside while loop it will print `Hello` and return 5.

Since it is greater than 0 `while` loop consider this as true and execute the statement below the while, which is `return 0`.

The `return 0` makes the `main` function to return 0 and stop the exeution.

The code

```
while(printf("Hello"))
    return 0;
```

is same as

```
while(printf("Hello"))
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Second Code:**

Since you used `;` after `while()` ,it will not execute the statement after `;`.
So the statement `return 0` is not executed and `while` checks the condition infinite times printing infinite `Hello`.

**Third code:**

While will execute the statements only within the `{ }`.

Since its empty every time after searching for statement it will go back and check the condition.

Since the condition is always true it will not reach the `return 0` and it will print `Hello` infinite times.